# sorting function - how can this be improved

Tags: java, sorting

I have the following code for sorting. Can this be improved?

```
import java.util.*;
class Church {
    private String name;
    private String pastor;
    public Church(String name, String pastor) {
        this.name = name;
        this.pastor = pastor;
    }
    public String getPastor() {
        return pastor;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setPastor(String pastor) {
        this.pastor = pastor;
    }
    public String toString() {
        return getName() + " is Pastored by "+getPastor();
    }
    public int compareByPastor(Church c) {
        int x = pastor.compareTo(c.getPastor());
        return x;
    }
    public int compareByName(Church c) {
        int x = name.compareTo(c.getName());
        return x;
    }
}

class Churches {
    private final List<Church> churches;

    public Churches() {
        churches = new ArrayList<Church>();
    }
    public void addWithoutSorting(Church c) {
        churches.add(c);
    }

    //You could always add using this method
    public void addWithSorting(Church c) {

    }
    public void display() {
        for(int j = 0; j < churches.size(); j++) {
            System.out.print(churches.get(j).toString());
            System.out.println("");
        }
   }
   public List<Church> getChurches() {
       return churches;
   }
   public void sortBy(String s) {
       for (int i = 1; i < churches.size(); i++) {
           int j;
           Church val = churches.get(i);
           for (j = i-1; j > -1; j--) {
               Church temp = churches.get(j);
               if(s.equals("Pastor")) {
                   if (temp.compareByPastor(val) <= 0) {
                       break;
                   }
               }
               else if(s.equals("Name")) {
                   if (temp.compareByName(val) <= 0) {
                          break;
                   }
               }
               churches.set(j+1, temp);
            }
            churches.set(j+1, val);
       }
     }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Churches baptists = new Churches();
        baptists.addWithoutSorting(new Church("Pac", "Pastor G"));
        baptists.addWithoutSorting(new Church("New Life", "Tudor"));
        baptists.addWithoutSorting(new Church("My Church", "r035198x"));
        baptists.addWithoutSorting(new Church("AFM", "Cathy"));
        System.out.println("**********************Before Sorting***********************");
        baptists.display();
        baptists.sortBy("Pastor");
        System.out.println("**********************After sorting by Pastor**************");
        baptists.display();
        baptists.sortBy("Name");
        System.out.println("**********************After sorting by Name****************");
        baptists.display();

    }

  }
```

Comment: It's unclear from the question how you want the churches sorted: by name, by pastor name? By size of the congregation? By steeple height?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at Collections.sort(list, comparator)
http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html

Comment: Write two custom comparators: one that sorts by pastor and one that sorts by name. When you want to sort by pastor, call `Collections.sort(yourList, pastorComparator)`. When you want to sort by name, call `Collections.sort(yourList, nameComparator)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Churches
{
    public void sortBy(String attribute) 
    {
      Comparator<Church> c = null;

      if ("Name".equals(attribute)) c = new ChurchNameComparator();
      else if ("Pastor".equals(attribute)) c = new ChurchNameComparator();
      else System.out.println("unexpected sort attribute : '" + attribute + "'");

      if (c != null) Collections.sort(churches, c);
    }

    private static final class ChurchNameComparator implements Comparator<Church> 
    {
      public int compare(Church c1, Church c2)
      {
        return c1.getName().compareTo(c2.getName());
      }
    }

    private static final class ChurchPastorComparator implements Comparator<Church> 
    {
      public int compare(Church c1, Church c2)
      {
        return c1.getPastor().compareTo(c2.getPastor());
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The real answer here is pretty much in line with iluxa's: you want to implement a Comparator interface on your Church objects (sample code [here](http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/5886), though you'll want to decide what constitutes greater than/less than for a church...), and then you can use Collections.sort() to sort them. That will get the job done, at the end of the day.

Of course, you just asked for advice about *sorting* on *Stack Overflow*, so I feel compelled to ask you if you need an in-place sort, what kind of Big-O performance you're looking for, and then ask you to choose between Quicksort, IntroSort, HeapSort, MergeSort, and StoogeSort for what will work best for you.

For kicks, I once coded up a few sorts in Java:

- [This one](http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/6419) forces Quicksort into quadratic time, which was harder to do than I'd originally assumed,
- This one shows how to implement [MergeSort](http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/6418),
- and this one demonstrates a [HeapSort](http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/6418)

I did these for my own enjoyment and education. As a general rule, you want to stick with the standard library for these sorts of things.